# window.onbeforeunload gets triggered in IE for Asynchronous calls?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, asynchronous, onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    someFunction();
}
```

Obviously whenever there is a page refresh someFunction() gets called. But in internet Explorer only whenever there is a partial page load someFunction() gets called as well. How can I prevent this from happening? Or how can I add an event listener with jQuery that gets triggered whenever an asynchronous call is made?

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods called during the life-cycle of an asynchronous request. You could tie into any number of them. See http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ for a list. This prevent you from bumping into different browser implementations like you did here.

For instance, using `$.ajaxSetup()` I can set a function to run before each request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
   console.log( 'New request going out.' ) 
  }
});
```

You may also want to run your logic once a call is completed, in which case you would apply a function to the `complete` member of the object passed to `$.ajaxSetup()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  complete: function() {
    console.log( 'Call completed.' );
  }
});
```

These methods have a couple arguments tossed their way, which you may want to use if you're performing logic that needs to know which requests specifically were made. Complete, for instance, will be passed the XHR Object used by jQuery, as well as the Status returned for the call.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  complete: function( jqHXR, status ) {
    console.log( 'Completed: ' + status );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but for some reason they don't get triggered. May be because the links that refresh the page partially are generated with the <asp:UpdatePanel> control? I don't know much about .net.

Comment: @SammyD These global callbacks will only get triggered when you make asynchronous calls using jQuery's ajax methods. Are you using jQuery's ajax methods to make your calls, or are you manually constructing your XHR Object?

Comment: no they're using jQuery's ajax methods. It's using <asp:UpdatePanel>.

Comment: @SammyD I'm sorry, your question made no mention of ASP.NET controls. I'm a PHP developer who has very little experience with ASP.NET. Please revise your question so somebody else may better assist you.